# Sorting words with pure insertion sort

Tags: c#, arrays, string, insertion-sort

I am trying to sort an array of words like this:

```
string[] myWords = {"banana", "egg", "apple", "bread"};
```

Is there any way I can rearrange them without using any `CompareTo`, `Sort` or other functions but just pure [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)?

My closest thing was converting all the words into char array but I can't seem to wrap my head around on how I would do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "insertion sort"?

Comment: Please make an effort to solve this by yourself first. If you run into a concrete problem with your attempted solution, post your code here and we will try to fix it. This meta post might be relevant: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: @Zohar Peled I think it refers to this algorithm: [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider probably, thanks. The .Net framework provides built in sort algorithms for practically every collection so it's been a long time since I had to think of a sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Jezzica You can't sort without comparing - the only order you'll get would be random.

Comment: @Zohar This is why I assume it is a homework assignment. For commercial software, you would just use the quicksort implemented by the framework.

Comment: The link you provided does do a comparison : f(head == NULL || current->iValue < head->iValue)

Comment: ..without "compare": "any array is sorted"! Who can disprove?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not excatly sure what you are asking for, so i will just assume:

If you want to sort this array without any compare opertaions, than you should use a distribution sort like [Radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)

If you want to sort your array without any build in sort method, than you have to create your own method. [Example Code](https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/searching-and-sorting-algorithm/searching-and-sorting-algorithm-exercise-6.php)